# ScrollTo() doesn't work properly if it running from MainActivity by onBackPressed()

Tags: java, android

If I start table.scrollTo(0,0) from MainActivity using the back button by onBackPressed (), it does not always work (almost never).  It is often necessary to press the back button a second time.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
         table.scrollTo(0,0);
}
```

The code bellow doesn't work properly too.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
         table.scrollTo(0,0);
         table.scrollTo(0,0);
}
```

...and this code too.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
        table.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                table.scrollTo(0,0);
            }
        });
}
```

If I run this method inside the table by double-clicking (onDoubleTap(MotionEvent event)), then scrollTo (0,0) always works properly.

```
@Override
public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent event) {
    scrollTo(0,0);
    return true;
}
```

I do not run the new thread. I create a table by onCreate()

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    table = new TableView(this);
    setContentView(table);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Place the Table layout in A HorizontalScrollView and the HorizontalScrollView in another Scroll view as in code below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:isScrollContainer="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/hScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <!--row and column-->
        </TableLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</ScrollView>
```

and in java file of activity call scrollTo method for both ScrollView and HorizontalScrollView as in code below

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ScrollView scrollView;
    HorizontalScrollView hScrollView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        scrollView = findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
        hScrollView= findViewById(R.id.hScrollView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        scrollView.scrollTo(0,0);
        hScrollView.scrollTo(0,0);
    }
}
```

These is working in my case , hope this will help you